# how to remove .php extension from the url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

there is no `.htaccess` file on my server website folder so i paste `.htaccess` file from other website in my website and write the rule as

```
RewriteRule ^terms-of-use$ terms-of-use.php [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy$ privacy-policy.php [L]
```

but does not work.

Comment: To clarify: does it actually work on your "other website", or was this an example bit of code you found somewhere?

Comment: i can not check this b'coz i deos not know the rule of .htaccess

Comment: You cannot just take a bit of code from somewhere and hope that it "works" (whatever works means here). What do you want to achieve and what do you see instead and where exactly do you have the code from? Edit this question fast or it will be closed.

Comment: @dave The `<!-- language: none -->` HTML comment is used to tell StackOverflow to not syntax highlight the code block here. This is because there is no suitable highlighter for `.htaccess` syntax, which would result in ugly colours.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteEngine On` above your RewriteRules.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

It would make (almost) any of your PHP files to work without the .php extension. The only exclusion is, for example:

If you have a file called `index.php`, and a directory called `index`, then it would prefer the directory first (as the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` tells the rewrite engine to only apply this rule, if the target is not a directory).

Comment: Consider also adding: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` to ensure the file exists before rewriting to it.